# Xamarin Android.App.DialogFragment Obsolete

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

**TL;DR** Does anyone know why `Android.App.DialogFragment` is obsolete in Xamarin and, more importantly, what class is recommended instead?

**More Info:**

I'm getting the following warnings in my Xamarin.Android app:

> Warning CS0618 'DialogFragment' is obsolete: 'This class is obsoleted in this android platform'
>   Warning CS0618  'Activity.FragmentManager' is obsolete: 'deprecated'

from the following code:

```
using Android.App;

void onClick(int pos) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new UsernameDialogFragment(_scans[pos]);
    newFragment.Show(_activity.FragmentManager, "dialog");
}

public class UsernameDialogFragment : DialogFragment {
    public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);
        // Build the dialog...
        return builder.Create();
    }
}
```

Note that I am using the `Android.App.DialogFrament` class, not the one in `Android.Support.V4.App`.  The `onClick` method is part of a `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

What is so frustrating to me about Xamarin issues like this is that there is almost never sufficient documentation.  The IntelliSense warnings don't recommend an alternative API, a Google search for "DialogFrament is obsolete" turns up nothing Xamarin-related except [this old](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/60208/an-obsotelete-problem-in-select-date-recipe) forum post recommending to *use* the obsolete API, and worst of all, the `DialogFragment` [API documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.DialogFragment/) doesn't even show that the class is obsolete!

Some version info:

Xamarin.Forms NuGet: v3.1.0.697729
Visual Studio 2017: v15.8.1
Target Framework: Android 9.0 (P)
Minimum Android version: Android 5.0 (API Level 21 - Lollipop)
Target Android version: Android 9.0 (API Level 27 - Oreo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the Android documentation, it is deprecated in Android **P**ie / API Level 28. Assuming the Xamarin documentation will get updated eventually as Android P was just released August 6, 2018, but I would recommend always reviewing the linked **official** Android documentation.

re: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment

> This class was deprecated in API level 28.
>
> Use the Support Library DialogFragment for consistent behavior across all devices and access to Lifecycle.

So, yes, the support libraries are the future (well...were the future), `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment` for right now, but those are being superseded by the Android extension libraries (`AndroidX`) and all future updates will be in those AndroidX libraries with only bug/security fixes being applied to the support libraries.

> The stable release of 28.0.0 will be the final feature release packaged as android.support. All subsequent feature releases will only be made available as androidx-packaged artifacts.

re: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/hello-world-androidx.html

Comment: Gah, you're right, I need to stop relying on the Xamarin docs (looks like they really just do a poor job of wrapping the Android docs anyway).  That `AndroidX` stuff is exciting news!  Any links for when the corresponding namespaces will be added to Xamarin?

Comment: @Rabadash8820 There is work being done on it by Xamarin but I have not seen a release date as some of the libraries are in 1.0.0-rc01 from Google and Google have stated those are production "safe", while others are not quite there yet, some alpha, etc... so I would *assume*(?) until Google releases final 1.0 versions, Xamarin will not release nuget-based wrappers for them : https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1709  (I have done a few binding libraries of them personally for one project that is only targeting Oreo & Pie and have not had any problems myself...)

Answer (score 2):

@SushiHangover's answer explains what my issue was.

For the sake of having a *Xamarin* code sample somewhere on the internet, here is the code that finally worked for me:

```
using Android.Support.V4.App;

void onClick(int pos) {
    var fragment = new UsernameDialogFragment();
    fragment.Show(_activity.SupportFragmentManager, nameof(UsernameDialogFragment));
}

public class UsernameDialogFragment : DialogFragment {
    public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);
        // Build the dialog...
        return builder.Create();
    }
}
```

Note that `_activity` must inherit `Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity`, otherwise you won't see the `SupportFragmentManager` property.

Answer (score 1):

you can use androidx library , it works well

public class NewDonorFragment(Your Fragment Name) : AndroidX.Fragment.App.DialogFragment {